Can Ubuntu 22.04 dynamically switch to external graphics card?
I have a Dell Precision 3530 with integrated Intel UHD Graphics 630 and an external Nvidia Quadro P600 card.  I'm using the nouveau driver for the Nvidia card.  lspci shows the Intel chip as the VGA controller and the Nvidia chip for 3D.  Is the OS switching between these automatically?  If not, what is the simplest way to force use of the Nvidia chip?  I just did a fresh install of 22.04.  I want to switch because I'm getting a flickering issue which I believe is due to the Intel controller, based on the bug reports I've seen.
